# How to unbind a key-board shortcut F2 on renaming file in eclipse java programatically

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to unbind the keyboard shortcut key F2 in eclipse java project/file.
how to do it programatically.Can anyone please help

Comment: Doing this programatically would require writing an Eclipse plug-in. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes through Eclipse plugin.Through code how  i can do it.Please help

Comment: I don't know of a simple API to do this. You can look at the source of `org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.model.BindingModel` to see what it does. This is the code used by the Keys preference page.